# Is there a way for multiple processes to share a listening socket?

Tags: sockets, concurrency

In socket programming, you create a listening socket and then for each client that connects, you get a normal stream socket that you can use to handle the client's request. The OS manages the queue of incoming connections behind the scenes.

Two processes cannot bind to the same port at the same time - by default, anyway.

I'm wondering if there's a way (on any well-known OS, especially Windows) to launch multiple instances of a process, such that they all bind to the socket, and so they effectively share the queue. Each process instance could then be single threaded; it would just block when accepting a new connection. When a client connected, one of the idle process instances would accept that client.

This would allow each process to have a very simple, single-threaded implementation, sharing nothing unless through explicit shared memory, and the user would be able to adjust the processing bandwidth by starting more instances.

Does such a feature exist?

**Edit:** For those asking "Why not use threads?" Obviously threads are an option. But with multiple threads in a single process, all objects are shareable and great care has to be taken to ensure that objects are either not shared, or are only visible to one thread at a time, or are absolutely immutable, and most popular languages and runtimes lack built-in support for managing this complexity.

By starting a handful of identical worker processes, you would get a concurrent system in which the *default* is no sharing, making it much easier to build a correct and scalable implementation.

Comment: I agree, multiple processes can make it easier to create a correct and robust implementation. Scalable, I'm not sure, it depends on your problem domain.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can share a socket between two (or more) processes in Linux and even Windows.

Under Linux (Or POSIX type OS), using `fork()` will cause the forked child to have copies of all the parent's file descriptors. Any that it does not close will continue to be shared, and (for example with a TCP listening socket) can be used to `accept()` new sockets for clients. This is how many servers, including Apache in most cases, work.

On Windows the same thing is basically true, except there is no `fork()` system call so the parent process will need to use `CreateProcess` or something to create a child process (which can of course use the same executable) and needs to pass it an inheritable handle.

Making a listening socket an inheritable handle is not a completely trivial activity but not too tricky either. `DuplicateHandle()` needs to be used to create a duplicate handle (still in the parent process however), which will have the inheritable flag set on it. Then you can give that handle in the `STARTUPINFO` structure to the child process in CreateProcess as a `STDIN`, `OUT` or `ERR` handle (assuming you didn't want to use it for anything else).

EDIT:

Reading the MDSN library , it appears that `WSADuplicateSocket` is a more robust or correct mechanism of doing this; it is still nontrivial because the parent/child processes need to work out which handle needs to be duplicated by some IPC mechanism (although this could be as simple as a file in the filesystem)

CLARIFICATION:

In answer to the OP's original question, no, multiple processes cannot `bind()`; just the original parent process would call `bind()`, `listen()` etc, the child processes would just process requests by `accept()`, `send()`, `recv()` etc.

Comment: Multiple processes can bind by specifying the SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress socket option.

Comment: But what's the point? Processes are more heavyweight than threads anyway.

Comment: Excellent, nice and simple. I didn't think of inheritable handles. Will try it and report back!

Comment: Looking very good, the child processes service the single queue of incoming connections as expected. I'll update my question with a link to a blog post when I get some time.

Comment: Processes are more heavyweight than threads, but as they only share things explicitly shared, less synchronisation is required which makes programming easier and could even be more efficient in some cases.

Comment: Moreover, if a child process crashes or breaks in some way, it is less likely to affect the parent.

Comment: There's a very nice example of this in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10088578/919436 which demonstrates a Twisted Python process spawning multiple child processes which all inherit the parent socket.

Comment: Also good to note that, in linux, you can "pass" sockets to other programs without using fork() and doesn't have a parent/child relationship, using Unix Sockets.

Comment: FWIW, on Linux there are no threads. Or rather threads are implemented as processes. Or rather processes and threads were refactored to have exactly the same implementation. The real difference is how much state is shared between parent and child. And for both you can opt to share more or share less. So you can start with a thread and create a process or start a process and create a thread or you can even go half way and have a semi-process or semi-thread.

Comment: only bind() should be called by the parent, listen() can be called by the child, I just tried it on the python program by @anil

Comment: For those who want to `bind` to the same port, socket option  `SO_REUSEPORT` is here for it, simply set this option on the underlying socket, then subsequent thread/process can bind to the same port (provided that these thread/process have the same uid). Such usage theoretically yields better scalability.

Answer (score 39):

Most others have provided the technical reasons why this works. Here's some python code you can run to demonstrate this for yourself:

```py
import socket
import os

def main():
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8888))
    serversocket.listen(0)

    # Child Process
    if os.fork() == 0:
        accept_conn("child", serversocket)

    accept_conn("parent", serversocket)

def accept_conn(message, s):
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Got connection from in %s' % message
        c.send('Thank you for your connecting to %s\n' % message)
        c.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that there are indeed two process id's listening:

```
$ lsof -i :8888
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Python  26972 avaitla    3u  IPv4 0xc26aa26de5a8fc6f      0t0  TCP localhost:ddi-tcp-1 (LISTEN)
Python  26973 avaitla    3u  IPv4 0xc26aa26de5a8fc6f      0t0  TCP localhost:ddi-tcp-1 (LISTEN)
```

Here are the results from running telnet and the program:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Thank you for your connecting to parent
Connection closed by foreign host.
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Thank you for your connecting to child
Connection closed by foreign host.
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Thank you for your connecting to parent
Connection closed by foreign host.

$ python prefork.py 
Got connection from in parent
Got connection from in child
Got connection from in parent
```

Comment: So for one connection, either parent or child gets it. But who gets the connection is indeterministic, right?

Comment: yes, I think it depends on what process is scheduled to run by the os.

Answer (score 16):

I would like to add that the sockets can be shared on Unix/Linux via AF__UNIX sockets (inter-process sockets). What seems to happen is a new socket descriptor is created that is somewhat of an alias to the original one. This new socket descriptor is sent via the AFUNIX socket to the other process. This is especially useful in cases where a process cannot fork() to share it's file descriptors. For example, when using libraries that prevent against this due to threading issues. You should create a Unix domain socket and use [libancillary](http://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/) to send over the descriptor.

See:

- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-share-socket-between-processes-289978/

For creating AF_UNIX Sockets:

- http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/817-4415/portmapper-51908?a=view

For example code:

- http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2002-January/000292.html
- http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SAMPO/Socket-PassAccessRights-0.03/passfd.c

Answer (score 13):

Looks like this question has already been answered fully by MarkR and zackthehack but I would like to add that Nginx is an example of the listening socket inheritance model.

Here is a good description:

- http://zimbra.imladris.sk/download/src/GNR-601/ThirdParty/nginx/docs/IMPLEMENTATION

> ```
>          Implementation of HTTP Auth Server Round-Robin and
>                 Memory Caching for NGINX Email Proxy
>
>                             June 6, 2007
>              Md. Mansoor Peerbhoy <mansoor@zimbra.com>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Flow of an NGINX worker process
>
> After the main NGINX process reads the configuration file and forks
>   into the   configured number of worker processes, each worker process
>   enters into a   loop where it waits for any events on its respective
>   set of sockets.
>
> Each worker process starts off with just the listening sockets,
>   since there   are no connections available yet. Therefore, the event
>   descriptor set for   each worker process starts off with just the
>   listening sockets.
>
> (NOTE) NGINX can be configured to use any one of several event
>   polling   mechanisms:
>   aio/devpoll/epoll/eventpoll/kqueue/poll/rtsig/select
>
> When a connection arrives on any of the listening sockets
>   (POP3/IMAP/SMTP),   each worker process emerges from its event poll,
>   since each NGINX worker   process inherits the listening socket. Then,
>   each NGINX worker process    will attempt to acquire a global mutex.
>   One of the worker processes will   acquire the lock, whereas the
>   others will go back to their respective event   polling loops.
>
> Meanwhile, the worker process that acquired the global mutex will
>   examine    the triggered events, and will create necessary work queue
>   requests for   each event that was triggered. An event corresponds to
>   a single socket   descriptor from the set of descriptors that the
>   worker was watching for   events from.
>
> If the triggered event corresponds to a new incoming connection,
>   NGINX    accepts the connection from the listening socket. Then, it
>   associates a   context data structure with the file descriptor. This
>   context holds    information about the connection (whether
>   POP3/IMAP/SMTP, whether the user   is yet authenticated, etc). Then,
>   this newly constructed socket is added   into the event descriptor set
>   for that worker process.
>
> The worker now relinquishes the mutex (which means that any events
>   that    arrived on other workers can proceeed), and starts processing
>   each request   that was earlier queued. Each request corresponds to an
>   event that was   signaled. From each socket descriptor that was
>   signaled, the worker process   retrieves the corresponding context
>   data structure that was earlier   associated with that descriptor, and
>   then calls the corresponding call back   functions that perform
>   actions based on the state of that connection. For   instance, in case
>   of a newly established IMAP connection, the first thing   that NGINX
>   will do is to write the standard IMAP welcome message onto the
>   connected socket (* OK IMAP4 ready).
>
> By and by, each worker process completes processing the work queue
>   entry   for each outstanding event, and returns back to its event
>   polling loop.   Once any connection is established with a client, the
>   events usually are    more rapid, since whenever the connected socket
>   is ready for reading, the   read event is triggered, and the
>   corresponding action must be taken.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure how relevant this to the original question, but in Linux kernel 3.9 there is a patch adding a TCP/UDP feature: TCP and UDP support for the SO_REUSEPORT socket option; The new socket option allows multiple sockets on the same host to bind to the same port, and is intended to improve the performance of multithreaded network server applications running on top of multicore systems.  more information can be found in the LWN link [LWN SO_REUSEPORT in Linux Kernel 3.9](http://lwn.net/Articles/542629/) as mentioned in the reference link:

the SO_REUSEPORT option is non-standard, but available in a similar form on a number of other UNIX systems (notably, the BSDs, where the idea originated). It seems to offer a useful alternative for squeezing the maximum performance out of network applications running on multicore systems, without having to use the fork pattern.

Comment: From the LWN article it almost looks like `SO_REUSEPORT` creates a thread pool, where each socket is on a different thread but only one socket in the group performs the `accept`. Can you confirm all sockets in the group each get a copy of the data?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Linux 3.9, you can set the SO_REUSEPORT on a socket and then have multiple non-related processes share that socket. That's simpler than the prefork scheme, no more signal troubles, fd leak to child processes, etc.

[Linux 3.9 introduced new way of writing socket servers](http://freeprogrammersblog.vhex.net/post/linux-39-introduced-new-way-of-writing-socket-servers/2)

[The SO_REUSEPORT socket option](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/)

Answer (score 3):

Have a single task whose sole job is to listen for incoming connections.  When a connection is received, it accepts the connection - this creates a separate socket descriptor.  The accepted socket is passed to one of your available worker tasks, and the main task goes back to listening.

```
s = socket();
bind(s);
listen(s);
while (1) {
  s2 = accept(s);
  send_to_worker(s2);
}
```

Comment: How is the socket passed to a worker? Bear in mind that the idea is that a worker is a separate process.

Comment: fork() perhaps, or one of the other ideas above.

Or maybe you completely separate the socket I/O from data processing; send the payload to worker processes via an IPC mechanism.  OpenSSH and other OpenBSD tools use this methodology (without threads).

Answer (score 3):

Under Windows (and Linux) it is possible for one process to open a socket and then pass that socket to another process such that that second process can also then use that socket (and pass it on in turn, should it wish to do so).

The crucial function call is WSADuplicateSocket().

This populates a structure with information about an existing socket.  This structure then, via an IPC mechanism of your choice, is passed to another existing process (note I say existing - when you call WSADuplicateSocket(), you must indicate the target process which will receive the emitted information).

The receiving process can then call WSASocket(), passing in this structure of information, and receive a handle to the underlying socket.

Both processes now hold a handle to the same underlying socket.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (that avoids many complex details) in Windows if you are using HTTP, is to use [HTTP.SYS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364510(VS.85).aspx). This allows multiple processes to listen to different URLs on the same port. On Server 2003/2008/Vista/7 this is how IIS works, so you can share ports with it. (On XP SP2 HTTP.SYS is supported, but IIS5.1 does not use it.)

Other high level APIs (including WCF) make use of HTTP.SYS.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is one process listening on for new clients and then hand off the connection once you get a connection. To do that across threads is easy and in .Net you even have the BeginAccept etc. methods to take care of a lot of the plumbing for you. To hand off the connections across process boundaries would be complicated and would not have any performance advantages.

Alternatively you can have multiple processes bound and listening on the same socket.

```
TcpListener tcpServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 10090);
tcpServer.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
tcpServer.Start();

while (true)
{
    TcpClient client = tcpServer.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("TCP client accepted from " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint + ".");
}
```

If you fire up two processes each executing the above code it will work and the first process seems to get all the connections. If the first process is killed the second one then gets the connections. With socket sharing like that I'm not sure exactly how Windows decides which process gets new connections although the quick test does point to the oldest process getting them first. As to whether it shares if the first process is busy or anything like that I don't know.