# How can non-exclusive ports exist when tcp identify applications using 16-bit port number?

Tags: c, network-programming

I can't come up with the exact socket api,but I remember that there is a socket option that demonstrates the port exclusive/non-exclusive.

If it's not exclusive,how can TCP know which application it should forward to for a specific destination port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be referring to the `SO_REUSEPORT` option available on some systems.

From the BSD man page:

> SO_REUSEPORT allows completely duplicate bindings by multiple processes
>   if they all set SO_REUSEPORT before binding the port.  This option permits multiple instances of a program to each receive UDP/IP multicast or
>   broadcast datagrams destined for the bound port.

Implementations vary a lot for this (from non-existant, to restricted to UDP, to allowing TCP also). In the cases where TCP is allowed, the connexions are distinguished by *both* source and target (ip,port) pairs. This is sufficient to allow the implementation to decide which app needs which packet. (see [Trek - Socket options](http://wiki.treck.com/Socket_Options) for instance.)

With multiple apps bind to the same TCP port, you could only have one socket `accept`ing on the port. The others would use the port to initiate outbound connections. The TCP stack always knows where to send the packets to.

- incoming packets that initiate (SYN) a connection go to the only accepting socket
- incoming packets for a connected stream are routed to the socket they belong to

Note: the sockets themselves (including, I believe the accepting socket) can be shared across multiple processes. See [Is there a way for multiple processes to share a listening socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670891/is-there-a-way-for-multiple-processes-to-share-a-listening-socket) for example.

---

Here's how it could work. Voluntarily simplifying TCP (no three-way handshake). Let's note the socket information held by the TCP stack like this

```
(socketname)[owner app, (local IP, local port), (state, remote IP, remote port)]
```

With that, let's set up three apps A, B and C:

```
App A -> bind (localhost,12345,SO_REUSEPORT)
    TCP stack: create socket (s1)[belongs to A, (localhost,12345), (not connected)]
App A <- s1

App B -> bind (localhost,12345,SO_REUSEPORT)
    TCP stack: create socket (s2)[belongs to B, (localhost,12345), (not connected)]
App B <- s2

App C -> bind (localhost,12345,SO_REUSEPORT)
    TCP stack: create socket (s3)[belongs to C, (localhost,12345), (not connected)]
App C <- s3
App C -> s3.listen()
    TCP stack: update socket (s3)[belongs to C, (localhost,12345), (open for business)]
App C -> s3.accept()
```

At this point, no data has been sent, but the kernel knows exactly what socket belongs to what application. Let's have A actually try to do something with its socket:

```
App A -> s1.connect(otherhost,54321)
    TCP stack: update socket (s1)[belongs to A, (localhost,12345), (connecting, otherhost,54321)]
    TCP stack: send SYN
```

Here, three things can happen:

incoming ACK packet from (otherhost,54321) with correct sequence: this is fine, it's for s1, no other possibility

```
    TCP stack: update socket (s1)[belongs to A, (localhost,12345), (connected,otherhost,54321)]
    TCP stack: send SYN/ACK
    TCP stack: notify App A that socket is connected
App A <- connect succeeded, you can start doin' stuff
```

incoming SYN packet from (client,4343): can only be for s3, only socket ready for SYN

```
    TCP stack: create new socket (s4)[belongs to C, (localhost,12345), (connected,client,4343)]
    TCP stack: send ACK to client
    TCP stack: notify App C that (s4) has been accepted
App C <- s4 returned from accept()
```

incoming packet from somewhere else:

```
    TCP stack: drop or reject, there are no matching sessions
```

Let's imagine the two things above happened. The kernel information is now:

```
(s1)[belongs to A, (localhost,12345), (connected,otherhost,54321)]
(s2)[belongs to B, (localhost,12345), (not connected)]
(s3)[belongs to C, (localhost,12345), (open for business)]
(s4)[belongs to C, (localhost,12345), (connected,client,4343)]
```

Now four kinds of packets can come in:

incoming normal packet from (otherhost,54321): this matches s1, hand it over to App A

incoming normal packet from (client,4343): this matches s4, hand it over to App C

incoming SYN packet from (otherclient,2398): this matches s3, same as before

anything else: drop or reject, invalid state

The TCP stack always nows which socket a packet belongs to. So it knows where to deliver the data.

---

`SO_REUSEADDR` is different: it only allows to bind to a port in `TIME_WAIT` state - i.e. the port is already closing down, the socket that had opened it has been issued a `close` already (more or less, there are other conditions). With `SO_REUSEADDR`, only one socket at a time holds the socket open.

Comment: how can TCP know which application it should forward to for a specific destination port?

Comment: it's not really a matter of selecting the application, it's a matter of selecting the right socket, which is doable with both source and destination (ip/port) pairs. What application uses which socket is not really a problem, that's dealt with like other I/O aspects (i.e. open files on Unix-like plateforms)

Answer (score 0):

A socket is identified by the IP address and the port - both. Together, in the BSD socket API, they are called a "name". You can bind your socket to a name and, if that name comprises a specific address, you can bind another socket to another name with the same port.

Also: a *connection* is a pair of two sockets, so a single address/port pair can be used in several connections - meaning more than one *connected* socket can have the same name (but not the same fd).

Comment: Can you illustrate by some examples?