# Why select() in a parent process makes accept() unusable in a child process?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, process

I have a parent process which creates 2 server sockets and calls `select()` on them to wait for new connection. When the connection arrives, a message is sent to a child process (created with `fork()`, after servers sockets creation, so they are shared).

In this child, calling `accept()` on the server socket doesn't work. I got a `EAGAIN` error (non-blocking socket). Whereas calling `accept()` in the main process works perfectly.

Of course, I don't call `accept()` in the main process at all, I just tested to check if it worked, and it does.

Why can't I call `accept()` in a child process after a `select()` in the parent?

EDIT: The goal here is to create a fixed number of workers (let's say 8) to handle clients connections, as in the prefork model. These connections will be long-connections, not like HTTP. The goal is to load-balance connections between workers.

To do this, I use a shared memory variable which contains for a worker the number of currently connected clients. I want to "ask" the worker with the lowest number of clients to handle a new connection.

That's why I do the `select()` in the parent, and then send a message to a child process, because I want to "choose" which process will handle the new connection.

The server listen on more than one sockets (one for ssl, one without), that's why I use `select()` and not directly `accept()` in children processes, because I can't `accept()` on multiple sockets in my children workers.

Comment: EAGAIN is not really an error per sé, it just means the call was non-blocking but there was no connection ready. Just sleep for a bit and try again. Any other error than EAGAIN, of course, is an actual error.

Comment: Why not call `accept` first before you fork? Specially since you know it works.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Could you please post some minimal code, to allow us to reproduce your observation?

Comment: Have you called `listen()` before or after forking?

Comment: I edited the question to add informations.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I should not get EAGAIN because select() returned that a connection is available.

Comment: @user1202136 Before, in the parent process. Children workers are created inly once, after socket creation (bind, listen, etc) so they inherit them.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Because I don't want to fork() for a each clients. Having 200 clients would mean 200 processes.

Comment: Could you copy-paste a small sample code which proves the problem. I think it would be really interesting for referencing, plus, it would help people check for themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FastCGI / SCGI pre-fork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797222/fastcgi-scgi-pre-fork)

Comment: @user1202136 I don't have "small" code, it's part of a my server implementation, splitted into a lot of Python classes. Anyway what is explained here seems to work with blocking sockets !

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Using blocking sockets worked. But I still don't understand why I got a EAGAIN error because select returned that my sockets is available for accepting connection. Anyway, I edited the post to give the solution.

Comment: If you open a file descriptor in a parent process, you can pass that descriptor to a child process using [Unix-domain socket magic](http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node121.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the problem was not what I first thought. Here is a recap of what I did to have some basic load-balancing of connections between my worker processes.

- A main process (the parent) creates 2 server sockets, bind() and listen() them (with and without ssl for example)
- I create 8 children processes with a fork(), so they inherit the parent's sockets
- The main process runs `select()` in an infinite loop
- When one of its two sockets is available, it sends a message to a child over a pipe. The child is determined thanks to a shared memory value, which contains the current number of clients "in the child process". The process which currently handle the lowest number of clients is chosen.
- This child process then calls `accept()` on the server socket (the socket to used between the two is passed in the pipe, so the child knows which one to call `accept()` on)

The problem was that my parent process told a child to accept the socket and re-enter the loop immediately after, which it runs `select()` again. But if the child has not yet accepted the socket, `select()` returns again, for the same connection. That's why I got a EAGAIN error, in fact I called `accept()` twice (or more depending on *speed* — *inter process race conditions*)!

The solution is to wait for the child to answer something on the pipe like "Hey, I accepted the connection, it's ok!", and then returns to the `select()` loop.

This works perfectly fine. The implementation in Python is available here for the curious : https://github.com/thibautd/Kiwi !