# websocket server node: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type

Tags: node.js, boost, websocket, ros, gazebo-simu

I have two ROS packages, each running a websocket server on the same PORT.

Is that's what's throwing this boost:: error?

```
node: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::transport::Publication; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = gazebo::transport::Publication*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

Is there a websocket server configuration that can allow two different ROS nodes to listen on the same PORT?

Thank you

Comment: What would it mean for both nodes to listen to the same port? Which one receives a new connection? It looks like it could be related only if there was a lack of error handling on binding the listener socket (bind/listen). Otherwise, it just looks as if Publication was accessed when it no longer exists. Or it was never initialized.

Comment: thanks @sehe 
This sounds plausible since this error 
is the very first output line upon npm start of the dual-node package, 
where one of the nodes creates a ROSlibjs topic, Subscribes it and then Publishes it (in that order).

Comment: in the case of this dual-node package, the first node is instantiated by the start script in package.json, and the second one is created within the main.js. 

The start-up order can be inverted, but I was getting the same boost error from either sequence.

Comment: can a WebSocket server support two ROS nodes (both essentially publishing and subscring but unrelated topics) on the same PORT or is that a conflict?

Comment: That is a conflict, in the current situation. You can see how it matches the last para in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/670897/85371

Comment: @sehe in regards to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/670897/85371 method(s), 
should I follow the Linux or Windows, to make this work on WSL2/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using this command worked for me.

`source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh`